# Extract HTTP body from curl response

Tags: perl, http, curl, response

I use package `WWW::Curl::Easy` for API calls, and this is my example code:

```
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new();

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'SOAPAction: "importSheet"']);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestMessage);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $tom::{'setup'}{'api'}{'carrier'}{'url'});


my $response;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, \$response);

main::_log(Dumper(\$curl));

my $ret = $curl->perform();
```

As you can see I save response into variable `$response`, but I would like to know what is the best way to extract only HTTP body of that response, without headers and stuff.

Now my response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 26 Nov 2021 21:38:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 241
Set-Cookie: TS01972c9d=01a27f45ea407d6a9622e8d70528d3201676317364865a22da7d73be308d9e49021a872fbfe71877fbee80ce454071bc9a105a4e33; Path=/; Domain=.test.test.com

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring>user_not_found</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but I would like to get only body of that response without headers so it should be like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring>user_not_found</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried stuff like:

```
$response_content = HTTP::Response->parse("$response") ;
$response_content = $response_content->content;
```

but it still contains headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *what is the best way to extract only HTTP body of that response*

Simply remove

```perl
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

Or change it to

```perl
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

---

If you also also want the header, then also add the following:

```perl
$self->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, \$head);
```

---

All together:

```perl
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new();

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POST,       1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL,        ...);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ...);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ...);

# $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  This is the default.
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,  \my $body);   # If you want the body.
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, \my $head);   # If you want the head.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, \$head)` and `$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_FILE, \$body)` to set separate destination for header and body data from response.

Comment: `CURLOPT_FILE` is the old name for `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`